# Bluetooth speaker not available in settings - Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: sound, bluetooth

Using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

- I can pair my bluetooth speaker
- I can see it paired, but when I look into the sound settings I can't see the bluetooth speaker present in the list and no setting obviously along side.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the output of `pactl list short modules` from a terminal.

Comment: similar problem here 
...
8 module-bluetooth-policy  
9 module-bluetooth-discover  
10 module-bluez5-discover 
... are all present